# Asynch splash activity does not appear

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I set the SplashActivity to be the first to be registered on application startup. Then in the postExecute method of my AsyncTask I start a new intent that takes you to MainActivity. Why does this not work? I don't get a single exception. The app simply opens to my MainAcitvity... Maybe I need to clean re-build the project a few times...

**Manifest:**

```
    <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

**Code:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASH_SHOW_TIME = 40800;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        new BackgroundSplashTask().execute();
    }

    private class BackgroundSplashTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SPLASH_SHOW_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i); finish();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your intent filter doesn't set the splash activity to open first or display on the launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file set **SplashActivity** as the follows:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then within your AsycTask , just remove `super.onPostExecute(result);` line of code from your `onPostExecute(Void result)` method. Also remove `onPreExecute()` implementation, it is not needed in your case.

```
private class BackgroundSplashTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(SPLASH_SHOW_TIME);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i); finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to add These two lines to your manifest SplashActivity

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

hope this helps.